# Hazelcast mapreduce executor overload

Tags: hazelcast

I'm setting up a new cluster and I'm getting an error from the hazelcast mapreduce executor:

`java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Executor[mapreduce::hz::default] is overloaded`

Using spring, I am configuring the jobtracker as follows:
`<hz:jobtracker name="default" max-thread-size="8" queue-size="0"/>`

Per documentation, 0 is the default queue size which is un-bound.

Thoughts?  I am only sending about 100 jobs simultaneously

Comment: This may answer the question, but it appears that queue-size 0 is the problem. Will test more, but a non 0 queue-size seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual is wrong about it. 
A value that's less or equal zero means that the queue size is twice the partitionCount.

`int queueSize = jobTrackerConfig.getQueueSize();
        if (queueSize <= 0) {
            queueSize = ps.getPartitionCount() * 2;
        }`

[Code snippet on github](https://github.com/tombujok/hazelcast/blob/106e89f207ef891e0b4b7fae736abf91e171a3cd/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/mapreduce/impl/NodeJobTracker.java#L49-L52)

Use an integer that's big enough for your use-case.